# SSH port forwarding: bind: Address already in use

Tags: ssh, gcloud, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have a remote server which I want to ssh it and forward my local port into it.

My application is hosting port 443 on my local machine. I'm connecting to the server with `gcloud`. This is the command:

```
gcloud compute --project "**^" ssh --zone "***" "***"
```

The *target* is to allow other to communicate, on port 9000, with the server and this traffic will redirected into my local machine, on port 443. On other words, accessing server on port 9000 is equal to access my computer on port 443.

So I do ssh port forwarding

```
gcloud compute --project "**^" ssh --zone "***" "***" -- -L 443:127.0.0.1:9000 -N
```

and get back this error:

```
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 443
Could not request local forwarding.
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct option is -R

```
... -R 9000:localhost:443
```

Answer (score 0):

> linux

if you have no other ssh connection you can fix it with :

```
killall ssh
```